# Difference between @ and # in Java toString output?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the @ and the # sign it the output of the toString?  I have a Java object that is not overriding toString.  In looking through the log file I see on some lines

```
com.foo.model.orders.Order@10eb9e65
```

while on another line (this one is emitted from hibernate) I see

```
com.foo.model.orders.Order#51a4cfa1e4b047bf2ab9b796
```

Is there a way to translate between these two numbers to determine if they are the same instance?

Comment: As Andrzej said, it's internal stuff. But after '@' is the result of `Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(object))`. But I can be wrong, because I don't really have any basis to prove that :P

Comment: Does your Order class use UUIDGenerator to assign primary keys? Any chance that 51a4cfa1e4b047bf2ab9b796 is a primary key of an Order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Both of those numbers are just arbitrary internal details from two different systems.  Neither makes a guarantee about what they are, or how they are worked out.

If you did come up with some sort of translation, it would be very brittle and prone to break without warning under any change of circumstances (different patch versions of libraries/JVM, running with a differently-sized heap, etc.).  And I suspect there probably isn't a link between the two anyway.  I know the first number is generated by the JVM typically based on the actual memory location that the object occupies.  The second will be some sort of hash generated by Hibernate - which doesn't have access to the same information as the JVM, and so likely won't be using the same input.

Answer (score 1):

The hash format, as you surmised, comes from Hibernate. To answer my own question from the comments to your question, Hibernate in several places logs the entity/class name, a hash sign, then the entity's primary key. So `com.foo.model.orders.Order#51a4cfa1e4b047bf2ab9b796` is the Order with primary key `51a4cfa1e4b047bf2ab9b796`.

As others have stated, if you want to check if two objects are the same instance, `==` will do that, more simply and reliably than comparing their string representations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine if the 2 object references refer to the same instance, use `Object.equals`

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

If you just want your log file to show enough information to determine if they are the same instance, override the `toString` to provide enough information, or change your logger message.

**---- EDIT ----**

To clarify per the @Jimothy comment, use `order1 == order2` instead of `.equals`

Comment: Better to just use `==`. It's true that `Object.equals()` is equivalent, but if a subclass overrides `equals()` (which, when using Hibernate, it generally should), then this is no longer true.

Comment: @Jimothy, agreed.  I stated object equals as a precursor to the quote as to what Object.equals is... but I see that I was not clear about that.